# How do I wait for Firebase to finish all write operations to the realtime database in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a batch process that updates several thousands of database references (with `update`) in Firebase realtime database in Node.js like this:

```
import { ref, update } from 'firebase/database'

...

let updates = [] 
... fill updates with dictionaries like { id: 1234, name: "abcd" } ...

updates.forEach((item) => {
    update(ref(database, "myitemtobeupdated/" + item.id), item) 
})
```

I need to exit the Node.js process once all of the write operations have completed to the database. How do I make sure that Firebase finishes all write operations?

I'm currently finishing the Node.js process as follows:

```
import { deleteApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'

...

getAuth().signOut().then(() => {
    log("Signed out")

    deleteApp(app)
        .then(function() {
            log("App deleted successfully")
            // NOTE: This exits the process
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            log("Error deleting app:", error)
            process.exit()
        })
})
```

... but I'm unsure if that also waits for the write operations to finish?

Comment: What exactly are you observing that suggests this doesn't work the way you expect?  `then` should only be invoked after all the work represented by the promise is complete.

Comment: I'm issuing several thousands of `update` operations in a very short time. I need to wait until the write operations are finished (written to the realtime database) before exiting the Node.js process. I updated the question with more information.

Comment: What exactly is `deleteApp`? The code you're showing that does the updates is not a complete function.

Comment: `deleteApp` refers to `firebase-js-sdk` function `deleteApp`, see here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/e5b96d77c27a158b0a103f2c3257436bebb86524/packages/app/src/api.ts#L240

Comment: So how you are you invoking the code that performs the updates?  It's really not clear how all this fits together.  You should provide a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) that anyone can copy and run to observe for themselves.